# MySQL Count the rows of which there are most

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a **businesses** table. I want to get the owners name who has the most businesses. So far all I only know that I need to use GROUP BY and HAVING.

The problem is I only know the most basic queries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help:

```
select owner, count(*) cntx
  from businesses
 group by owner
 order by cntx desc
 limit 1
```

Or executing the query without `limit 1` clause, and then iterate the result till your needs are satisfied.

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks :) Sorry for the slow resposne tho

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and order descending and then take the top one record which is the one that has most businesses:

```
select OwnerId, count(*) from businesses
group by OwnerId order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```